# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cm_Cache_Backend_File' not found

Tags: composer, magento2-enterprise, php-7.2

Going through an upgrade from 2.2.6 to 2.3.1 and i have this populating on the frontend.

Additionally, on command line if i try to run an upgrade or pretty much anything even `php bin/magento list` i throw this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ListenerOptions' not found in /srv/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php:41
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(747): Zend\Mvc\Service\ModuleManagerFactory->__invoke(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'ModuleManager', NULL)
#1 /srv/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php(195): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->doCreate('ModuleManager')
#2 /srv/public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Application.php(35): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('ModuleManager')
#3 /srv/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php(71): Magento\Setup\Application->bootstrap(Array)
#4 /srv/public_html/bin/magento(22): Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->__construct('Magento CLI')
#5 {main}
  thrown in /srv/public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Service/ModuleManagerFactory.php on line 41
```

I'm desperate here, i feel like i've tried about everything.

Comment: Are you able to see the below file ? 

$DOCROOT/vendor/zendframework/zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ListenerOptions.php

Comment: Actually no... none of these directories exist zend-modulemanager/src/Listener/ListenerOptions.php

Comment: It seems to be some issue with the code upgrade that was done. you can try reinstalling using composer update. If it does nothing then you can try moving the vendor/magento folder to somewhere else (maybe in your home folder for backup) and then retry composer update. That should probably bring back the missing files and solve your problem

Comment: @ArifAhmad I made a backup of the vendor folder and reran composer update but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Can you also try clearing the composer cache before retrying?